# Multiple XAMPP and apache instance running on the same computer at the same time

Tags: apache-http-server, website, xampp, multiple-instances, flask

Is there any possibility to have three versions/instances of XAMPP or Apache running at the same time?

I have a server which mainly includes a release, a release candidate, and a development website. The reason that I need three XAMPP or Apache instances is that when I'm doing something new to the website, I want to test first the functionality on the development website.

The changes that I made are in Flask (Python), javascript, HTML, and they are not automatically loaded to the website.  For loading, a restart of the Apache service needs to be done. Of course the restarting will also restart the other websites (release one and release candidate one).

Comment: Each instance would have to run on it's own port, but a single instance, can handle multiple individual websites already so it isn't actually necssary to run multiple instances of Apache.

Comment: This question on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660066/hosting-multiple-local-sites-with-xampp

Comment: @Ramhound . I know it's possible to host multiple websites via vhosts but I don't want to use vhosts. Because if i use virtual hosts, when a new change is done on a specific website, I must restart Apache in order to load the configuration on the website, and If i restart Apache all the other websites will go down(during restart) and I don't want this. I'm not sure if you understand what i want.

Comment: @user3664679 - If you feel I don't understand your question, then you will have to clarify your question, by eidting it.  You can certainly run multiple instances of Apache.  However, it seems strange you have to restart the Apache service, in order to perform an update on your website.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any possibility to have three versions/instances of XAMPP or Apache running at the same time?

As pointed out in the comments, yes, but each instance would have to run on its own port. That is, two of the three couldn't run on port 80 (they would be accessed via `host:port`).

If you wanted all three to be accessible on port 80, the third instance would need to be set up as a [reverse proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) for the first two. The drawback here would be any restart of the reverse proxy would still affect access to any proxied instances. The better solution might be to have a fourth copy of Apache as a reverse proxy for all three of the other instances (so, ideally, it wouldn't  need to be restarted).

---

*One other consideration might be differing service names, assuming you wanted these instances to run automatically.*

---